# How to resolve Internal Server Error when using webservices in CN1

Tags: codenameone

How to resolve  Internal Server Error using webservices in CN1.
I am facing this problem when trying to interact with the mysql database using webservices. I was trying to insert into the database. when I monitor the network in the simulator. this is what I am getting in the post body:

```
{"birthday": "ADMIN",
"password": "test1@weblite.ca",
"name": "ade",
"bio": "ADMIN",
"email": "testpass1"}
```

I am getting this in response headers

```
null=[HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error]
Connection=[close]
Content-Length=[1876]
Date=[Tue, 24 Jan 2017 12:36:39 GMT]
Content-Language=[]
Content-Type=[text/html]
```

Pls what am I missing here that I can't insert record into the database? Thanks

```
[EDT] 0:0:0,31 - Find request failed. Response code was 500
[EDT] 0:0:0,31 - Exception: java.lang.NullPointerException - null
java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.mycompany.myapp.IAPDemo$1.lambda$fetchReceipts$0(IAPDemo.java:87)
at    com.codename1.ws.RESTfulWebServiceClient.lambda$find$7(RESTfulWebServiceClient.java:234)
Java Result: 1
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 2 minutes 2 seconds)
```

That is what I am getting as the full error. if anyone can figure out what I am missing here pls should tell me. thanks

Answer (score 0):

The clue should be in the words "Internal Server Error". 500 errors are errors that happened within the server. You need to login to the server and look at the logs within the server.